# Given a curve, under which condition is the set of gonal morphisms finite 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rational-functions, riemann-surfaces, moduli-spaces

Recently, in my research I bumped onto gonal morphisms. At the moment, my knowledge is based upon some things I read on the internet. Before stating my questions, I added some definitions/facts that might motivate the questions below.

By a curve, I mean a smooth projective connected curve over $\mathbf{C}$. A non-constant morphism $\pi:X\longrightarrow \mathbf{P}^1$ is *gonal* if $\deg \pi$ is minimal. The *gonality* of a curve $X$, denoted by $\gamma_X$, is the degree of a gonal morphism $\pi:X\longrightarrow \mathbf{P}^1$. Thus, for example, a curve of genus $g\geq 2$ is hyperelliptic iff it is $2$-gonal.

The hyperelliptic map of a hyperelliptic curve is unique. (Of course, here by unique we mean *unique up to composition with an isomorphism of the projective line*.)

Edit: In the questions below, we consider the set of gonal morphisms of a curve modulo the action of Aut$(\mathbf{P}^1)$.

**Fact 1.** For any curve $X$ of genus $g\geq 2$, we have that $\gamma_X \leq [\frac{g+3}{2}]$.

**Fact 2.** For any integer $\gamma \geq 2$, the closure of the locus of $\gamma$-gonal curves in the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_g$ of smooth curves of genus $g\geq 2$  is 
irreducible of dimension $2g-5+2\gamma$.

**Fact 3.** For any prime number $p$ and integer $g\geq 2$ such that $g\geq (p-1)^2$, Accola showed that any $p$-gonal curve of genus $g$ has a unique gonal morphism.

I can't prove these facts, but I do remember where I got them from. So if necessary I could give the references.

**Question 1.** Let $X$ be a $\gamma$-gonal curve of genus $g\geq 2$. Is the set of gonal morphisms for $X$ *modulo the action of Aut$(\mathbf{P}^1)$* finite?

I expect the answer to this question to be negative if $g-\gamma$ is small. In view of Fact 3, I would like to propose the following question.

**Question 2a.** Fix $\gamma\geq 3$. Does there exist an integer $g_\gamma$ such that for any $g\geq g_\gamma$ and any $\gamma$-gonal curve $X$ of genus $g$, the gonal morphism for $X$ is unique?

**Question 2b.**  Fix $\gamma\geq 3$. Does there exist an integer $g_\gamma$ such that for any $g\geq g_\gamma$ and any $\gamma$-gonal curve X of genus $g$, the set of gonal morphisms for $X$ is finite?

**Question 3.** Does there exist a positive integer $g_0$ with the following property? For any $g\geq g_0$ and curve  $X$ of genus $g$, the set of gonal morphisms of $X$ is finite?

**Question 4.** Do there exist curves with infinitely many gonal morphisms? (Edit: In hindsight, this question is the same as Question 1.)

I think it's clear that these questions aren't unrelated. They are all related to the set of gonal morphisms associated to a curve. It would be wonderful to know when this set is finite.

Comment: About question 4: a smooth plane quartic  $C$ has gonality 3 and has infinitely many $g^1_3$, corresponding to projecting to ${\mathbb P}^1$ from a point of $C$.

Comment: thank you for this answer. What is $g_3^1$ stand for? I came across this notation a couple of times. Could you give a definition? I'm guessing $g_3$ means gonality three? What does the 1 on top mean?

Comment: I do not understand the difference between Q.1 and Q.4. If you do not divide by  the action of $Aut({\mathbb P}^1$ then you always get infinitely many gonal morphisms.

Comment: Generalising rita's example, a general curve of genus $g > 2$ with $g$ odd has a $1$-dimensional family of gonal morphisms; this can be seen by counting parameters. In contrast, for general curves of even genus there are only finitely many gonal morphisms. (See the book by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths and Harris "Geometry of Algebraic Curves, Volume I" for more information.)

Comment: A $g^1_3$ is a linear system on a curve of degree 3 and (projective) dimension 1. In general, a $g^r_d$ is a linear system of degree $d$ and dimension $r$, so the gonality $\gamma$ is the smallest $\gamma$ such that $C$ has a $g^1_{\gamma}$. 

Comment: @rita: i should have said i always mod out the set modulo the action of Aut$(\mathbf{P}^1)$.


Comment: @ulrich: Did I understand correctly that your comment implies a positive answer to Question 3 if we stick to curves with even genus?

Comment: No. This will only be true for general curves, i.e. curves corresponding to some non-empty Zariski open subset of the moduli space $M_g$.

Comment: as an example generalizing rita's and confirming ulrich's comment, consider a smooth plane quintic, which has genus 6 and gonality 4, and project from points of the curve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending Rita's example, if $X$ is, say, a double cover of a curve of genus $3$, then $X$ can have arbitrarily large genus and it has gonality (at most) $6$. Moreover it has infinitely many $g^1_6$ (BTW $g^r_d$ means a linear system of degree $d$ and dimension $r$, so a $g^1_d$ is a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$). So the answer to all of your questions is no.

Here is something that can be done. If you have two maps of degree $d$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$, then you get a map from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. If this map is injective, then the genus of $X$ is at most $(d-1)^2$ (or something like that). So if the genus is large, there must be a map $X \to Y$ such that any map of degree $d$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ factors through $Y$. If $d$ is prime, this cannot happen, hence your fact 3.

Comment: A $g^1_d$ is not exactly a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$ (since it can have basepoints)... But nice answer!

Comment: What is your curve $Y$ in the second paragraph?

Comment: @Ariyan: The image of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$, if the map is not injective, which will happen if the genus of $X$ is large enough. If you want to consider all maps of degree $d$ then you need to prove that there is a $Y$ that works simultaneously for all of them.

Comment: Ow yes of course. I get it now. Concerning the first paragraph of your answer: there are only finitely many double covers of a given genus 3 curve, right? So to get a negative answer to my questions, one has to consider all  genus 3 curves, right? So just to be sure, for each such curve  $X_3$ we take a double cover $Y_3$ of $X_3$ of genus $g_{Y}$, where $g_Y$ is a function on $\mathcal{M}_3$ going to infinity. (hmmm...I think I'm writing down things a bit too complicated here.) Anyway, the point is that the genus grows but the gonality is bounded, right? 

Comment: There are infinitely many double covers of any curve. I am not fixing the ramification.

Comment: In your example the gonality is precisely 6 for $g$ large enough. Assume the curve has a $g^1_d$ with $d<6$. Then you get a birational map $C\to D\subset {\mathbb P}^1\times X=:S$. By construction $DK_S=8−2d\le 8$ and by the index theorem $2D^2\le(2+d)^2\le 49$. So $p_a(D)\ge g$ is bounded.

Comment: Probably another stupid question, but what is $C$ and what is $D$? How's the birational map $C\longrightarrow D$ defined? Moreover, which index theorem are you using here? Hodge index?

Comment: Sorry for the messy notation. $C$ is a  curve of genus $g$ which is a double cover of a plane quartic $X$, $D$ is the image of $C$ via the map $f\times g$, where $f\colon C\to X$ is the double cover and $g\colon C\to {\mathbb P}^1$ is the $g^1_d$.
The Hodge index theorem is applied to $D$ and $\{pt\}\times X+{\mathbb P}^1\times\{pt\}$.